# Bootstrap full width buttons .btn-group-vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
<a href="3overview.php" class="btn btn-primary">Overview</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
<br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make it so these buttons are full-width of the container that they are in but I can't seem to get it to work, I have tried .btn-group-justified but nothing works with .btn-group-vertical. Can someone help?

**EDIT 11/28/2017: Marked the accepted answer and fixed some typos I found.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The btn-group-vertical has an automatic set width of 85px as far as I can see. Setting it to 100%, fixes your problem. It should be done in a stylesheet, but under is an inline solution:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width: 100%;">
<a href="3overview.php" class="btn btn-primary">Overview</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
<br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** While this works, I'd go with Vlads answer instead. It is better than mine. And works as well. Although, you do not have to add the class to the individual buttons. Adding the class to the button group is enough. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block" style="width: 100%;">
        <a href="3overview.php" class="btn btn-primary">Overview</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        <br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add the width via inline style, just put the button group in a row and give it a col width.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical col-12">
            <a href="3overview.php" class="btn btn-primary">Overview</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
            <br>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Button</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The most simple answer!

Answer (score 0):

To make button full width, just add `btn-block` class to button. Take a look at this - [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_button_block&stacked=h)

Comment: it doesnt answer the quetion, he is speaking about button-groups